# InvalidCastException unit testing with InMemoryDatabase after EF Core 5 update

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

*Note: This appears to be a different issue from this other question as my problem pertains to Expressions and has nothing to do with NetTopologySuite or Owned types: [InvalidCastException after upgrading to EF Core 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64779031/invalidcastexception-after-upgrading-to-ef-core-5-0)*

I am having a number of unit tests fail after finally updating my project from EF Core 2.2 to EF Core 5.0. All are failing with a variation of:

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryRootExpression'.

For example, as a follow up to this question of mine: [Translating query with GROUP BY and COUNT to Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58102821/translating-query-with-group-by-and-count-to-linq)

I updated my query to the EF Core 3.0+ example given in the accepted answer, the only change being I am using a defined class in the results instead of an anonymous type:

```
var countData = await _context.Sale
    .GroupBy(s => s.InternalUser.UserName)
    .Select(g => new SaleCountSummary
    {
        UserName = g.Key,
        InsertCount = g.Sum(s => s.Version == 1 ? 1 : 0),
        UpdateCount = g.Sum(s => s.Version > 1 ? 1 : 0),
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

This queries the `Sale` table to see how many rows each `InternalUser` has inserted and how many they have updated based on the `Version` number in the row.

This throws the aforementioned exception when called from a unit test using the InMemoryDatabase, but it translates to SQL and works just fine in my application against an actual SQL Server database.

Comment: Sounds like you should file a bug report at https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues - out of interest, what happens if you change it back to using `Count()` with a predicate?

Comment: @IanKemp same error if I go back to the EF Core 2.2 query.

Comment: @Valuator, instead of using InMemory store, switch to SQLite in-memory. Looks like this store become less maintained.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, I'd like to and have looked into it in the past but our `DbContext` is too dependent on SQL Server functions for default values ex. `.HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())")`